# Converting time to readable form in R

Tags: r

```
10/16/2011  9:33:46 AM
10/16/2011  9:54:48 AM
```

The above are a few rows from my G$time column. I wanted to convert them to readable form when I graphed Y over Time, so I tried

```
Time<-strptime(G$Time,format="%D  %H:$M:%S %r")
```

and then

```
Time<-strptime(G$Time,format="%m/%d/%y  %H:$M:%S %r")
```

but it's not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: The correct format for a 4 digit year is %Y, not %y. Also you do not have seconds so don't put them (or that %r item in because these are not 12-hour times) in the format string. And furthermore you should not use 2 spaces in your format when there are only one space in your input data. (And this is really an R forum question.)

Comment: Hi DWin, thanks for your responses. In the data I downloaded, there are 2 spaces after the 10/16/2011. When you say this is really an R forum data, do you mean I should post this on a different site?

Also, what if I have "AM" or "PM" after the time? That means I should put in the r% there, right?

Comment: A) I see you edited the question so there are now two spaces in data. The R formum I was talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

Comment: Yeah, I realized that my copying/pasting of the four rows from Excel didn't capture the entire timestamp format, which may have engendered some obvious errors in my attempt. Thanks for the link! I actually had this crossposted, but I'll choose one forum from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these have a better chance:

```
Time<-strptime(G$Time,format="%m/%d/%Y  %R")  # %R is equiv to %H:%M

Time<-strptime(G$Time,format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:$M")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how you're reading in the data when I put : a =10/16/2011 9:33
into the command line I get the error : Error: unexpected numeric constant in "10/16/2011 9".
I think you should read it in as two variables convert them into seconds, and then add them together.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Adam. My time data is actually in the format "10/16/2011  9:33:46 AM" (I unfortunately had accidentally left failed to copy over the seconds and the AM part before). I tried DWin's solution below, and it worked when I didn't have the AM in my dataset. But now I'm trying again with 10/16/2011  9:33:46 AM and 

'Time<-strptime(Time,format="%m/%d/%Y  %H:$M:%S %r")' and... still trying to find my error, haha.

Comment: ETA: figured it out over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924166/converting-time-to-readable-form-in-r-x-posted-on-stats. Thanks.